# AVFoundation isn’t reading a specific type of barcode

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode-scanner, zbar

I’m building an app for paying parking tickets. The problem is that we have a specific type of barcode that AVFoundation can’t read.

I tried to found other frameworks to replace the AVFoundation, but turns out all of them use AVFoundation underneath. The only framework I found capable of reading it is the ZBar, but we’re not planning to use it since it hasn’t been updated for 6 years.

Do you guys have any idea why it isn’t working?

Image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEU0H.jpg

Thank you.

```
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.QRCode")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.PDF417")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.gs1.UPC-E")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.Aztec")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.Code39")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.Code39Mod43")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.gs1.EAN-13")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.gs1.EAN-8")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("com.intermec.Code93")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.iso.Code128")
    allowedBarcodeTypes.add("org.ansi.Interleaved2of5")
...
func metadataOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    //videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj)
    if metadataObj != nil {
        let barCode = Barcode.processMetadataObject(metadataObj)

        for str in allowedBarcodeTypes{
            if barCode?.getType() == str as? String && !didReadCode{
                    didReadCode = true
                    self.barCode = barCode?.getData() ?? ""
                    self.stopRunning()
                    if let navController = self.navigationController {
                        delegate?.getScannedCode(scannerNavigationController: navController, code: self.barCode)
                    }
                    return
            }
        }
        if didReadCode == false {
            self.invalidBarcodeFound()
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not easy to point out why doesn't you code work when you didn't post any code whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry @mag_zbc, didn't think it'd be necessary, because I can read any other type of barcode, the problem is just with the one I mentioned above.

Comment: And do you know its type at least?

Comment: @Larme, according to an Android barcode scanner, it's ITF format.

Comment: Does't AVFoundation has the: `AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.itf14`? Shouldn't you add it?

Comment: @Larme I've already tried it. But the `allowedBarcodeTypes` is checked inside the  `metadataOutput `, and this `metadataOutput ` isn't even being called.

Comment: @Matheus Alano, I've stumbled in this exact same problem. Have you made any progress since this question was made?

Comment: I haven't @Naslausky. I left the company a few months after the question and we hadn't found the solution.